# Is there a constant for the Maximum Unsigned Long value in an Arduino compiler?

Tags: arduino-uno, compiler

I am writing a timer function that uses the micros() function which generates a unsigned long value.  To compensate for a roll over condition, I would like to use the maximum value for that variable type.  I have a number, 4,294,967,295, but was expecting that to be a constant somewhere.

Is there a MAX_UNSIGNED_LONG constant in the Arduino compiler files somewhere?

I have tried that name and know it probably isn't that.  Still poking around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Various `limits.h` files in the `avr-gcc` hierarchy define `ULONG_MAX`, which may be the value you want.  For example, on my system such files have paths ending with `hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.1/include-fixed/limits.h` or with `hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.1/install-tools/include/limits.h` and contain definitions like the following.

```
/* Maximum value an `unsigned long int' can hold.  (Minimum is 0).  */
#undef ULONG_MAX
#define ULONG_MAX (LONG_MAX * 2UL + 1UL)
```

Note, `LONG_MAX` also is defined in `limits.h`.

Note, arithmetic done in a form like

```
timeDelta = micros() - prevTime;
```

will be correct (regardless of whether `micros()` overflowed) for elapsed times up to 2³² microseconds, or about 4295 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need "to compensate for a roll over condition".

See my answer: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/33577/10794

---

> in an Arduino compiler?

The "Arduino" compiler is a C++ compiler. That is the starting point for most questions. If you Google for:

```
maximum unsigned long in c++
```

You will find the first link leads to:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

In that it says:

```
ULONG_MAX   Maximum value for an object of type unsigned long int
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to do this?:

```
unsigned long maxUnsignedLong = 0UL - 1UL;
```

or:

```
const unsigned long ULONG_MAX = 0UL - 1UL;
```